# AngularJS Form Validation - Bind input to model eventhough there is input error

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I have a form using the built in angularjs form validation and ng-messages. Look at this code.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form1.firstName.$invalid && form1.firstName.$touched }">
<label class="control-label">* First Name</label>
<input name="firstName" ng-model="applicant.firstName" required ng-pattern="alpha" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="30" type="text" class="form-control" />
<div class="help-block has-error" ng-messages="form1.firstName.$error" ng-if="form1.firstName.$touched">
    <div ng-messages-include src="/worktrustedV2/app/modules/core/templates/errorMessages.template.html"></div>
    <div ng-message="pattern" class="error" style="color:red">This field requires letters only</div>
</div>
```

If the input doesnt trigger an error, then if you console.log($scope.applicant.firstName);, it prints the value, but if the input has an error, console.log($scope.applicant.firstName); becomes undefined.

Is there a way to make angular(or maybe it because of ng-messages) bind the input's value even if it has error? I want to make console.log($scope.applicant.firstname); to print the value even if the input has error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: After you rephrased the question

I remember I was facing the same problem when writing an application; when you have 10000+ lines of code, you can imagine the situation. Now, if I understand it clearly, you WANT `applicant.firstName` to have SOME value even if the validation fails? If that's the case, let me explain to you how Angular works.

Whenever you define a field as an `ng-model`, the internals of Angular manage two values for this field:

1. $modelValue
2. $viewValue

As you might have guessed from the names of these variables, $modelValue is the value of the input instance to be used by the model, and the `$viewValue` is used for displaying it, etc. ([AngularJS ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController))

Our good friends at Angular have done something pretty useful: whenever the input field doesn't pass the test, the `$modelValue` is set to undefined. So, when you try to get the value of that model, Angular sees that it's empty and so returns an undefined. Also, when the validation fails, `<parentForm>.$invalid` is switched to `true`.

For your case, you can give it a default value; so, even if the validation fails, you'll get SOME value.

Simple add:

```
$scope.applicant.firstName = "example@gmail.com";
```

in the controller to get a value even after the validation fails.

---

Yeah! You can check if the value if undefined and break out of the function. That's the best method.

```
...
$scope.submit = function() {

    if( $scope.firstName === undefined || 
        $scope.firstName === null ) { return; } 

    ... // Continue normal execution

}
```

Comment: Im sorry but thats not what Im looking for. Maybe, I should rephrase my question.

Comment: Yeah! Sounded a little confusing.

Comment: I finished rephrasing my question. I guess its not confusing now.

Comment: Ah I see. I learned so much from this answer. But what if  I have so many ng-models? So I have to assign a default value to each?

Comment: Well, yes. But you can write a small function to automate that. :)