# Get text-field's value in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text-field form in my html in which I wish to extract to my controller.

Currently it always returns "undefined"

[image]

HTML:

```
<center>
    <button ng-click="RequestSubmit()" class="button button-assertive">
    Submit Request!
    </button>
</center>

<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">Remarks</span>
 <input type="text" ng-model="remarkstext">
</label>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ctrl', function($http, $scope, dataFactory) {
$scope.RequestSubmit = function($scope){

var t = $scope.remarkstext;
console.log("remarks: "+t);
```

Removing the "$scope" in the function() does not work. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't see the controller defined the way it should; are you sure that's all you have in the controller? Also, you're passing the `$scope` as a parameter; I've had problems with that. Try removing the `$scope` from the `RequestSubmit` function.

Comment: @weirdpanda : yes it's defined correctly. I just pasted the relevant codes.

Comment: @weirdpanda, edited!

Comment: remarks.text ?? you dont have a model call remarks.text, it's just remarks, remove $scope from function !

Comment: `remarks.text` can't possibly work as the model you've defined is `remarkstext`.

Comment: You have passed the $scope argument in RequestSubmit but it is not needed and since you have not passed any argument in the ng-clcik thus its getting undefined. Just remove the $scope argument in the function.

Comment: @SujataChanda, three comments have already mentioned that! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you dont want to use $scope.remarkstext then pass remarkstext in
>   ng-click.
>
> **NOTE**: if you want to access model value in controller then you have to use $scope.remarkstext.
>
> you are using **remarkstext** directly so it will give you error
>   undefined.

use like this if you want value from parameter

```
<center>
    <button ng-click="RequestSubmit(remarkstext)" class="button button-assertive">
    Submit Request!
    </button>
</center>

<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">Remarks</span>
 <input type="text" ng-model="remarkstext">
</label>
```

```
$scope.RequestSubmit = function(remarkstext){

var t = remarkstext;
console.log("remarks: "+t);
}
```

---

**your mistake**

```
$scope.RequestSubmit = function($scope){

var t = $scope.remarkstext;
console.log("remarks: "+t);
}
```

i don't understand why you are using $scope in function parameters 
you can directly use $scope.remarkstext inside function.and remarkstext is in **ng-model** so it is available in **$scope** .[ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)  to see scope tree in console.

---

Comment: Hi , the reason is that i do not fully understand $scope. Thank you!

Comment: Imagine `$scope` as an object which holds everything for the current controller. The `$scope` is two-way: what you do on/in the scope is reflected in the View as well. Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: @weirdpanda , thanks so much! i really appreciate your help but yet i cannot double upvote here! But i find your other answers really helpful!

Comment: @Gene install  ng-inspector.   i given link in answer it will help you to find nested scope parent scope etc.....

Comment: @KevalBhatt, i'm developing on ionic platform, i'm unable to use it. But it's a cool add-on Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PzTZmtgyLHfVYbkogKpt?p=preview):

**html:**

```
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="remarkstext">
 <button ng-click="RequestSubmit()" class="button button-assertive">
    Submit Request!
    </button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.remarkstext='';
$scope.RequestSubmit = function(){
console.log($scope.remarkstext);
}
```

Comment: Thanks kai! Your setting of "remarkstext" to ' ' gave me some ideas what went wrong.

Comment: writing  $scope.remarkstext=''; is not complusory. But i generally prefer to write so because sometimes scope willnot be updated according to the changes made in view.Initilizing scope.value will prevent such kind of problem (mainly in case of arrays).

Answer (score 1):

USe this code::

```
.controller('ctrl', function($http, $scope, dataFactory) {
    $scope.RequestSubmit = function(){

    var t = $scope.remarkstext;
    console.log("remarks: "+t);
```

Comment: Thanks! I guessed the problem is that i did not pass the value into the submit button even thou i removed the "$scope" from the function.

Answer (score 1):

As @weirdpanda said in his comment, you have to remove `$scope` from the `RequestSubmit` function. Note that this function expects a parameter, and you are calling it without anyone. So in `RequestSubmit` function, `$scope` is undefined.

About the definition of your controller, it is not bad, but take into account that if you minify your code it won't work, you should define like this:

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$http', '$scope', 'dataFactory', 'StoreService', function($http, $scope, dataFactory, StoreService) {
    ...
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will minify my code properly next time! (:

Answer (score 1):

@jjimenez has mentioned very correctly that you're using a function which expects a parameter without passing it any. This confuses the internals of AngularJS as it MAY think of that as a special extension function.

You **have** to remove the `$scope` from the function; furthermore, a very common coding standard is (it actually makes the code a lot more readable and easier to work with):

```
.controller( 'ctrl', [ '$scope', '$http', 'dataFactory', function( $scope, 
                                                                   $http, 
                                                                   dataFactory ) {

    $scope.RequestSubmit = function() {
        console.log( "Remarks: " + $scope.remarkstext );
    };

    // ... rest of the logic

}] );
```

After minification the old code wouldn't have worked because of the fact that when UglifyJS (or equivalent) minifies it, it renames the reserved variables `$scope`, etc. to `e` `a` or something else, which Angular is unable to resolve; when you use the `array notation` (I forgot its specific name), angular knows what to inject, only the names have changed.

Coming to your problem, one thing can be that you're trying to click the button before filling in the text; as you can read one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591553/angularjs-form-validation-bind-input-to-model-eventhough-there-is-input-error/33591630#33591630), I have explained how the `ng-model` works. Give that a read, and check!

If possible, can you give us a little bit about how you've defined your controller; in the context of HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur prompt reply and your detailed answer! I guessed the problem is that i did not pass the value into the submit button even thou i removed the "$scope" from the function, thus the value did not  update still.